# Is it possible to mark iOS app as local app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

The App Store includes a 'Explore' tab, that lets the user explore some apps that can be used in the surrounding area. My app is doing the same, but how and where can I define that location?

I am close to release, so I don't know if Apple is doing this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple uses an algorithm, based on the users geographic location when he or she downloads the app. Therefore, if many people in a certain area download a specific app, it will be shown in the "popular near me" list.

Sources: [cultofmac.com](http://www.cultofmac.com/242642/near-me-feature-in-ios-7-app-store-starting-to-work-for-certain-beta-testers/), [tune.com](http://www.tune.com/blog/marketers-popular-me-feature-ios7/)

Comment: Where do you know this form?

Comment: Check the first paragraph of [this](http://www.cultofmac.com/242642/near-me-feature-in-ios-7-app-store-starting-to-work-for-certain-beta-testers/) article